# How Read JSON Data From URL In SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, json

I'm trying to read JSON data from a URL in SQL Server 2008, using this code:

```sql
DECLARE @temp table (RowNum int, DATA NVARCHAR(max))
DECLARE @url VARCHAR(MAX),
@win INT,
@hr INT,
@Text VARCHAR(8000),
@RowID int,
@Status smallint,
@Accuracy tinyint

Set @url = 'http://www.jsonprovider.com/api/json/2020'
EXEC @hr = sp_OACreate 'WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1', @win OUT
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win

EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @win, 'Open', NULL, 'GET', @url, 'false'
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win

EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @win, 'Send'
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win

EXEC @hr = sp_OAGetProperty @win, 'ResponseText', @Text OUT
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win

EXEC @hr = sp_OADestroy @win 
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win 

select  @Text  --<< Result
```

AND I get my result.

The problem is the process to get this result takes 7 sec in SQL Server, but in normal call by C# application and calling in web browser I get my result in 0.06 sec.

I looking for a solution for improving my code to get a fast result.

Comment: You are trying to read JSON data from a webpage directly into sql? Why? Why not read it in c# and pass it in. From your numbers that would be much faster.

Comment: I was able to use this code to read json text from a url by changing the ole object name to MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP with fast results.

Answer (score 7):

This is an example of "just because you can, doesn't mean you should".

SQL Server is not the right tool for this job; the fact that it works at all is amazing. If you want to speed it up, put in in a c# or php program and let SQL server do that job it was intended for. Processing jSON responses is not one of them.

Comment: oK I did it [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19393860/asynchronous-output-from-clr-function/19394303?noredirect=1#comment28746076_19394303) ???

Comment: This is an axample of "this is not an answer".

Answer (score 2):

E.J. explained it quite well, I agree with him.

I would like to add that if you want to keep everything in database code you can try [CLR procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094%28SQL.100%29.aspx) that are essentially written in C# but work inside SQL Server.

See these links for details on how to do this in C#

[HTTP request with post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/http-request-with-post)
[How to make a GET request by using Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307023)