# Asynchronous output from CLR function

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have create a CLR function like this

```
public class GETJSONFROMURL
{
   [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
    public static SqlString GETData(SqlString URL) 
    {
        SqlString Data = "N/A";


        using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {

            var json = webClient.DownloadString(new Uri(URL.ToString()));
            // Now parse with JSON.Net
            JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);
            Data = (string)o["Data_results"]["MyData"];


        }
        return Data;


    }
}
```

and made a function in Sql Like this

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY GetDataURL
FROM 'C:\GETJSONFROMURL.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS

CREATE FUNCTION GetDataURL (@URL NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX) WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
EXTERNAL NAME GetDataURL.GETJSONFROMURL.GETData
```

when I select this function in query window  I get result very fast under 0.03 sec

```
SELECT [dbo].[GetDataURL] ('http://www.Testserver.com/123')
```

but when I call this function as multiple call , like inside Triggers after insert something call that select I get delay for get result .

can you please help me to create an  asynchronous function which is when I call inside sql as multiple call  didn't get  delay for returning result .

thanks

Comment: Oh my.  Your CLR SQL function makes an HTTP call **on every row**.  That will, obviously, be exquisitely slow.  Needless to say, you can't possibly take advantage of *any* async pattern since the function *must* return a value immediately.  (custom CLR functions in SQL server are supposed to be **fast** -- excessive calculations are bad, let alone making a network call to some other server)  I am about 100% certain that this notion of baking this logic into the SQL tier is completely inappropriate and should be handled in the calling code.

Comment: I did It before but get result inside sql is very slow 4.6 sec because of that I create CLR

Comment: Why would you think it would be *better* to make the database server do this rather than the application?

Comment: To further @Andrew's point, you should always keep in mind that, generally speaking, SQL tiers can only scale vertically.  Clearly, most people who enjoy relational databases also ensure at least a minimum of database checks (FK/UK integrity, etc.), but the underlying goal of ensuring the DB doesn't do *too* much work should always be considered.  In other words, you want the DB to help ensure it maintains only *valid* data, but extracting JSON from a web service just so the client (presumably one that can scale horizontally) doesn't have to do that work doesn't even begin to qualify.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing this inside a trigger, you *could* create a SQL Server Agent job that updates the table every 5 minutes (or more or less often depending on your requirements).

The job could call your CLR function once for every row that doesn't have the data inserted yet.

However, I would strongly suggest you make the client-side software get the data from the URL and insert it into the table.

You could consider having a separate machine get the json data for newly inserted rows; this takes the load off the SQL Server, and allows the client to not worry about getting the data.

Comment: Yes it's good  Idea But the problem is we need live data and that data check by customers take time  ... and also we need this happening in our end because we calculate some result over live data and can not wait for Agent Job to done the process   .

Comment: if you need the data live, you need to have the client-end get the data and insert it with the rest of the row.

Comment: Ok  I did It [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307704/how-read-json-data-from-url-in-sql-server) ????