# I'm having trouble retrieving data product from cloud database in JSON format

Tags: sql, ssms

I'm supposed to retrieve product data from a cloud database in JSON format. This is the link of the data: http://bi.edisonsiow.com/ay1516s2/ca1/getProducts.php

How am I supposed to do it? I'm using SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Well, SQL Server currently doesn't have any native support for JSON - so you'll probably need some kind of regular programming language (C#, Ruby, VB.NET - whatever) to read and interpret that JSON and then insert it into the SQL Server database

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) Can you elaborate a little bit more? I don't really get how to do it

Answer (score 0):

this link might help you....

> https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/

it creates a TSQL function to read json

Comment: it is not the best practice but if you want to use SQL only  than see this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307704/how-read-json-data-from-url-in-sql-server